# How to use predict_proba on a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, mlflow

I've been using AutoML in databricks and I have some troubles using a trained model for inference.

The model I chose from the experiment was registered, and the notebook that trains that model has some instructions for using that model for inference. Also, from the model registry I have an option for using the model for inference, but none of them allows me to make a predict_proba. The only way I've found to make a predict_proba is on a pandas dataframe, but I want to do it on a pyspark dataframe.

Following the instructions from the notebook, I registered the model using

```
model_name = 'Example'
model_uri = f'runs:/{mlflow_run-info-run_id}/model'
registered_model_version = mlflow.register_model(model_uri)
```

And I loaded the model using

```
model_version = registered_model_version.version

model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri=model_uri)
```

Finally, for inference, I can use `model.predict_proba(data)`, whenever `data` is a pandas dataframe, but I can't do the same on a pyspark dataframe.

I'm pretty new to pyspark and databricks, so I'll be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a custom function and not built-in in pyspark, you'll need to create a user-defined function (udf), something like this:

```
predictUDF = udf(lambda x: model.predict_proba(x), DoubleType())
```

Then you can apply this function to your dataframe df like:

```
df.withColumn("prediction", predictUDF(data))
```

You may need to tweak a bit depending on which columns to pass etc. To make the UDF you can use a lambda function or use @udf as a decorator to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Log the model using this parameter to return the positive-class predicted probability for a binary classifier

```py
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(
    # ...
    pyfunc_predict_fn="predict_proba"
)
```